# Controllers want a Key still if the new class is based on another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing this-

File -> new project -> Visual C#  .Net Framework 4.5. -> ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Application.

I am creating a class Personne and a class Etudiant deriving from Personne (under the models folder)

Personne.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;  
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace TestTryHelper.Models
 {
     public class Personne
     {
         public int PersonneId { get; set; }
         public string Nom { get; set;}
         public string Prenom { get; set; }

     }

     public class Etudiant : Personne
     {
         public string Ecole { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

I am trying to add a HomeController  (Controllers/  ADD/ Controller)

Controller Name:  HomeController
Scalfolding options
Template : MVC controller with read/write actions and views using Entity Frameworkd
Model Class: Etudiant (TestTryHelper.Models)
Data context class:  
  in the window New Data Context   TestTryHelper.Models.TestTryHelperContext
click OK
Views: Razor
Click ADD

I got this error message

```
 Unable to retrieve metadata for 'TestTryHelper.Models.Etudiant'.
 One or more validation errrors were detected during mode generation:

 -System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntity,Type:  EntityType 'Etudiant'
 has no key defined.  Define the key for this EntityType.
 -system.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet ' Etudiants' is based on type    
 'Etudiant that has no keys defined.
```

For some reason it is working for other people.  I can fix this by adding a EtudiantId under the Etudiant Class.

Anyone will know why it is working for some people and not for other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the property `PersonneId` to just `Id` I think it will work for both types. Alternatively, decorate the `PersonneId` property with the `[Key]` attribute, which will indicate to EF what property you want to use as the table key:

```
 public class Personne
 {
     [Key]
     public int PersonneId { get; set; }
     public string Nom { get; set;}
     public string Prenom { get; set; }

 }
```

You may also have to add this to the top of your code:

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Comment: I tried with only Id instead of PersonneId and effectively it works.  I will like to try your other option but I can figure out how to put the key [ ]  can you show me how to do this please.  Thanks

Comment: Both of your solution fix my problem.  Thanks for your generous help.

Comment: When I tried to rerun after the changes, I got a problem with model context has changed since the DB was created, any way to regenerate the model ?  I can't find any .edmx to regen  I used code first

Comment: You need to either delete the db and gave the code regenerate the db or alter the db yourself to match the poco classes.

Comment: @Terry  I have deleted the db still got the same error.  poco classses?